# Autoplaying video in WebView URL

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webView.loadUrl("somewebsitewithvideo.com");
```

This command lets me Autoplay the video in the URL of my webview.. which worked in that sense.  The problem is this "Start Video Playback" button that is still there unless I click it to go away.  How can I remove this button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `webView.evaluateJavascript()` to run javascript code after page finish loading.

### Example:

assume you have a function in your `js` files called `playVideo()` you can run this function by calling `evaluateJavascript` like this:

(Optional:  `playVideo` function may return some value you can handle it also)

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("playVideo()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        // Handle return value
    }
});
```

Comment: Will it safe to allow javascript run in webview?

Comment: just to be clear .. so i can try this at work tomorrow.. i should run some JS script to click the button for me using this function that allows me to do so?  if so i guess i gotta do some research on how to do that further.. thank you for your input

Comment: @K.Sopheak it's safe until you enabled the bridge between javascript and java functions.